# Flash CS6 - Text and text inside of symbols

Tags: text, flash-cs6

I've just recently started learning flash, but have come across two things to which I can't seem to find an answer / explanation.

---

First:

http://puu.sh/bEPnB/64aaafa203.png

Here, there's a symbol (the frame) and two textfields all placed on the stage. As you can see, the text fits nicely within.

http://puu.sh/bEPpx/826ff331c9.png

Here, I attempted to place text inside of the symbol.

Why is this happening, and can it be "fixed"?

---

Second:

I set all my dynamic textfields to "Times New Roman" - bold italic and embedded the font. When testing, all the textfields show appropriately. However, if i change the value of one, it reverts to "Times New Roman" - regular.

Why don't dynamic textfields retain bold / italic, but do keep properties such as paragraph aligning, font size, etc?

Answer (score 0):

1. Flash IDE has a bug - sometimes when changing TextField's size in editor (by clicking and draging blue dots - manipulators) flash changes scale parameter, not width and height, as it should. Try inserting new TextField and change size by editing width/height manually in properties panel.
2. Did you select the proper character range in embedding options?
   Also be sure to not use "Use device fonts" Anti-alias setting. You can find this setting in TextField's properties panel.